# Stencil texture mapping doesn't match object

Tags: uv, texture-painting

i want to paint a wooden texture on an object using stencil brush.
that object formed from a cube, using boolean and bevel modifiers - that i apply them to my cube, and now i have this 3D object:

[image]

i use smart unwarp for unwarping, but my texture doesn't match correctly on my object! in viewport it looks like this:

[image]

but in render result, it exports like this:

[image]

i thought it's for complex object, but i had same problem with texturing a single cube!
can anyone help me? :)

Comment: What does your shader node tree look like - are you connecting a texture mapping node to the image texture node that is feeding into your shader, and is it using the UV mapping as coordinate?

Comment: @CraigDJones my nodes are look like this: https://imgurl.ir/uploads/f522624_.jpg

Comment: Try changing to 'Flat' mapping instead of 'Tube' in your Texture node - if your UV map is as it shows there in the screenshot, then you should be using flat mapping and not box or sphere, tube etc.

Comment: @CraigDJones Thank you! it works nice :)